# Render html stored in a string as real html on page

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I want to this to work. I am using svelte.

```
let value = "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
```

```
<div class="main">
    {value}
</div>
```

Comment: What is it currently doing?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0oPdWet

Comment: Consider editing your question to include more details. A description of the problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Svelte's html directive with `{@html value}` to output `value` as raw HTML.

See the [Svelte docs for @html](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-html).

Comment: @Hector would you mind marking my answer as the correct one so others having a similar problem can find this quicker?

Comment: There should be a note that a) this rarely should be necessary and b) this opens you up to **XSS vulnerabilities** if the input is not sanitized

Comment: @H.B. Does that matter if you use stuff thats readonly like a div for example? Like where users can't input information themselves.

Comment: @Hector: It's safe if there is no user input, i.e. you know exactly what is in there. But then again, in that case you really should not need it in most cases.